# Countdown timer not working properly

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to use this `timer`...when I call `countDownTimer.start()`

I can                     see in the debugger that the timeleft variable get updated to the `value=120000`                   that I want but the timer doesn't execute the `onTick` method. It jumps straight                         to `onFinish`. But if I give `timeLeft` a literal it works.

```
    volatile long timeLeft=0;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer( timeLeft,1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long timeLeft) {
            TextView timeView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
    long longTime=(timeLeft / 1000);
    Integer intTime=(int)longTime;// convert long to int
    timeView.setText(String.valueOf(intTime));}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {correctDialog("Sorry,Time Is Up!!");}};}


    (timeLeft is not fixed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the first parameter in the `CountDownTimer()` constructor is the `millisInFuture` . You are giving this value as 0. So it will finish whenever you start the timer. Give its value how much time you want to execute the times like 10000 or 20000 etc...

So initialize timeleft

```
volatile long timeLeft=10000;
```

Check the documentation [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: Thanks. This how the app is supposed to work. In the onCreate method, there's a call to a method that checks whether the app is running the first time/is an update or is normal. If it's normal, it calls another method which reads a file to check the value of the time stored in the file, and i am sure that is working. After that it updates time left to most recent time. from there a call to the timer to start is made. So,i cannot make timeLeft=0;

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + String.valueOf(seconds));
         }
         public void onFinish() {
             tv.setText("Finished!!");
         }
      }.start();
}
}
```

**Xml:-**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I think it's solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The thing is 30000 must not be a fixed value but a variable. If a user press a button then the timer starts, if he press the same button again it must stop and when he press it again it resumes the countdown from where it ended the last time.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `timeLeft = 0;`this means that the timer would run for 0 milliseconds. the `timeLeft` should equal to the amount of milliseconds you want the timer to run for. So, for a thirty second timer, `volatile long timeLeft = 30000;`

Hope this helps

Answer (score -3):

Code for **CountDownTimer**:

```
int tickTime = 1000; //For every second
int finishTime = 30000; //Complete of countdowntimer

TextView yourTextView;

new CountDownTimer(tickTime, finishTime){

    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
       Log.i("CountDownTimer", "onTick");
       yourTextView.setText(String.valueOf(l));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
       Log.i("CountDownTimer", "onFinish");
    }
}.start();
```

This countdowntimer comes on **every second** in **onTick()** method and after **30 seconds** it will come in **onFinish()** method.

**Done**

Answer (score -3):

Precise Answer to the question is, you forgot to start the timer.

i.e. you missed `countDownTimer.start();`